# Where To Add File Save Method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am saving an array that is editable by the user to the plist.  My question is, where in the code to I implement the code?  Like one of the methods dealing with the app quitting?

This is the code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"patientList.plist"];
[myPatients writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: If you are saving an array, it might make more sense to look into the coredata framework and save your data to a database.

Comment: I'm not using CoreData because I haven't got a chance to learn it yet and I want to get my product to the market ASAP.  I will probably learn it and implement it in a revision.  My data model is pretty basic so .plists with arrays and dictionaries should be fine for now.

Comment: Right, but once you are at market, you have no concept of migrations. I.e. the format of how you store your data (i.e. the schema) may change, and if it does, you will have to identity the version of the app and write migration code to get there data to version 2.0. CoreData is not hard to learn, and it is 'the right way' to tackle a problem such as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on how you've implemented your data manager.  If you have a singleton to handle accessing / writing data, why not just write data to the file as your singleton array is updated? This way you can be sure data is always saved should something unexpected happen.

What Jordan suggests is definitely one route, but I would use the appWillResign vs willTerminate.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, any more info on this?  I'm not familiar with singleton

Comment: You don't need to be using core data to use a singleton. Singleton is a design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which consolidates, in this case, all your data access/manipulation to a single instance of an object (there is never more than one instance).  Some don't like it b/c it is essentially global state but I find it works very well for data.  The short of it is a class with an init and class method (typically named sharedInstance) and any methods. you call like [[YourSingleton sharedInstance] writeData:YourArray].  [AppDelegate sharedApplication] is a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        [self saveCode];
    }

    - (void)saveCode
    {
      SArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"patientList.plist"];
    [myPatients writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks, and should I put this in the app delegate right? not the viewcontroller that is presenting the array.

Comment: AppDelegate us correct and there is a syntax error in your original code for NSArray. In addition myPatients needs to be defined to the AppDelegate.

Comment: I referenced the class where myPatients is defined, isnt that supposed to work?